# "export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular

When we upgrade the angular **version** **8** to **9** then it is show the following error during `ng serve`.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow guide to upgrade angular from 8.0 to 9 official docs. [This one](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0)

Answer (score 3):

`Renderer` had been deprecated for some time now, and finally removed in Angular 9. You should migrate to `Renderer2`.

https://angular.io/guide/migration-renderer

Comment: can we downgrade the version? I try to multiple time but angular version not change .

Comment: @AyushSahu you can downgrade by running `npm i @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8`, assuming you were on version 8. Sometimes your package.json and package-lock.json will get out of sync and your project will use what's inside of the package-lock.json file. So now, run `npm i` to sync them up. If you still run into problems after that, run `npm ci` to do a completely clean install of your dependencies.